# Can I use the C# 8 range operator with a list instead of an array?

Tags: c#

The following code compiles:

```cs
var ints = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray();
var subset = ints[2..^2];
```

But this code doesn't:

```cs
var ints = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
var subset = ints[2..^2];
```

[image: error message]

The error message is, as you can see from the picture above, `cannot convert from 'System.Range' to 'int'`.

Why is it that the C# 8 range operator only seems to work with arrays and not with lists? How do I use it with a list?

Comment: You should be able to use linq 'Take' instead i.e: 
```var subset = ints.Take(2..^2);```  
See https://dotnetfiddle.net/To2sYo